# How create java class object in javascript using RHINO

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

How create CUSTOM `java class object` in java-script using `RHINO`..?

We can use classes which is in `rt.jar` but not other custom class

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an `Object` which is of a type not found in rt.jar? Or you actually want to create a `Class` object?

Comment: i just wants to create an object of a class which is not found in rt.jar that mean it was written by me....on any one..
BY useing Rhino

and also how can  implemented in eclipse if u can...

Comment: Hello Simon, maybe you could rephrase your question to say what you actually seem to be asking, in case other people look it up. As I understand it, you are asking how to use a custom Java Class from inside an Eclipse Environment. And also, please don't use "PLZ HELP" or similar phrases in your questions, they don't add any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. compile class use a package
2. make a jar file
3. set classpath of that jar
4. use importPackage(Packages.)
5. start rhino..
6. now it will work.